# Odd transparency issues with SVG converting

Tags: vb.net, svg, type-conversion, svg-transforms, svgtopng

I'm trying to convert SVG images to jpeg or png (quality doesn't matter)

I'm using a NuGet package named [SVG](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/3.1.1?_src=template).

Here's my vb code

```
Dim svgDocument = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(TextBox2.Text & "\" & filename & ".svg")    ' Replace with correct FileName                                      
                Dim bmp As Bitmap = svgDocument.Draw(100, 100)                            ' Draw Bitmap in any Size you need - for example 12px x 12px                  
                bmp.Save(TextBox2.Text & "\" & "jpeg" & "\" & filename & ".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)                 ' save Bitmap as PNG-File
```

The thing that's working wrong is: The background of the text becomes black. Which is not like that when I look at them in a browser.

Deleted

And here is the original file of the SVG

[Deleted][3]

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong, thanks for your time.

Comment: You have to post the SVG source code also, not just the code that does the conversion. I suspect its a styling setting IN the SVG declaration

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not exactly sure about how to post it so I've added a link of original svg file. I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your SVG](http://keremomersah.byethost5.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/32.svg) is full of `image` elements with base64 encoded PNGs:

[image]

if you paste those:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQ4AAACVCAIAAAAmBYPGAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAjElEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQo/oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK4G2BYAAb1+fN8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

into: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image

You can see its a black image:

[image]

See F12 network tab:

Looks like all text are images with a black background

[image]

Comment: I guess I'll find a way to clear them. Thank you very much !